# I dont get why this code for my Game of Life doesnt work. Can anyone help me?

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

The Problem is when I start the code the game kinda works but it doesnt behave like the normal conwys game of life. So I thought my logic section where the neighbours are checked doesnt work as I it should. After long debugging I still couldnt find the mistake. :)

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JPanel {

private Field field;
private JFrame frame;

public GUI() {
    int width = 800, height = 800;
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(this);
    field = new Field(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
        j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 400; j++) {
            if (field.getAlive(i, j)) {

                g.drawRect(2 * j, 2 * i, 2, 2);
                g.fillRect(2 * j, 2 * i, 2, 2);
            }
        }

    }
    check();

}

public void check() {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 399; i++) {
        j = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < 399; j++) {
            if (field.getAlive(i, j)) {

                int x = 0;
                if (field.getAlive(i - 1, j - 1)) {
                    x++;
                }
                if (field.getAlive(i, j - 1)) {
                    x++;
                }
                if (field.getAlive(i + 1, j - 1)) {
                    x++;
                }
                if (field.getAlive(i + 1, j)) {
                    x++;
                }
                if (field.getAlive(i - 1, j)) {
                    x++;
                }
                if (field.getAlive(i - 1, j + 1)) {
                    x++;
                }
                if (field.getAlive(i, j + 1)) {
                    x++;
                }
                if (field.getAlive(i + 1, j + 1)) {
                    x++;
                }

                if (x < 2 || x > 3) {
                    field.setAlive(i, j, false);
                } 

            } else {


                if (!field.getAlive(i, j)) {



                    int x = 0;


                    if (field.getAlive(i - 1, j - 1)) {
                        x++;
                    }
                    if (field.getAlive(i, j - 1)) {
                        x++;
                    }
                    if (field.getAlive(i + 1, j - 1)) {
                        x++;
                    }
                    if (field.getAlive(i + 1, j)) {
                        x++;
                    }
                    if (field.getAlive(i - 1, j)) {
                        x++;
                    }
                    if (field.getAlive(i - 1, j + 1)) {
                        x++;
                    }
                    if (field.getAlive(i, j + 1)) {
                        x++;
                    }
                    if (field.getAlive(i + 1, j + 1)) {
                        x++;
                    }

                    if (x == 3) {
                        field.setAlive(i, j, true);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    repaint();
   }

  }



   public class Field {
   private GUI gui;
   private int fieldLength = 1;
   private boolean[][] alive;

  public Field(GUI gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
    alive = new boolean[400][400];
    for(int i = 100 ; i<110; i++){alive[100][i] = true;    }
    for(int i = 100 ; i<110; i++){alive[i][100] = true ;   }
  }

 public boolean getAlive(int i, int j) {
    return alive[i][j];
  }

 public void setAlive(int i, int j, boolean alive) {
    this.alive[i][j] = alive;
  }

 }
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to dump. You should have managed to narrow it down a bit if you debugged it. Have you ensured neighbours are being counted correctly? Have you verified the live/die logic?

Comment: And are you checking the same board that you're updating? That will cause corruption.

Comment: You have to create a new Field every generation. You can't update the same field that you're checking.

Comment: Yeah I checked the neighbours and the live/die logic but I dont get what you mean with your second comment.

Comment: If you're updating cells on the same field that you're currently checking, youll get corrupted patterns. It won't behave as a standard GoL implementation. Look up a good GoL tutorial.

Comment: It's difficult to describe in comments, but that's definitely your problem.

Comment: A common mistake to make when implementing Conway's game is to forget that it is the next depends on the current turn, and if you partially update your array as you check it, then you can mess up your neighbor counting as a new born or new death changes a count to an incorrect value.  I don't see you doing something like copying the current map, or using a type other than Boolean to represent a cell

Comment: Also you should add comments to your code, without comments this is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, it doesn't work, can someone help me figure it out"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused because you are using the same board instance for checking the rules and for updating. Every iteration you should create a new board based off the old one instead of re-using the old board.

You should maintain two boards at any given time. One to read from and one to write to then just copy the written one at the end of each iteration

Comment: Ah thanks I got it :)